# Visual Studio extensions keep disappearing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am by no means a visual studio expert. However I have done some searching on this topic and cannot find anything to help me.

I'm working on a VS 2010 web application. We are using TFS 2012 for source control. I wouldn't be suprised if this is causing my issue so I make a special mention of it.

The issue I'm having is every morning after I open the project I have to go into Tools / Extension Manager and search online and add `JScript Editor Extensions`. When I open the project the next day it's gone and I have to add it again. (I think sometimes it does this right in the middle of coding - my Javascript window changes size and loses formatting)

An extension that stays every day regardless is `NuGet package manager`, so it's not removing *every* extension.

I suspect that when I get latest from TFS it's overwriting the solution or project which contains the reference to the extension but I haven't been able to verify this.

Can anyone tell me why extensions would be removed? Are these a local user setting or are they contained in the project file?

Taking a step back, my real problem is complete lack of integration between C# and Javascript in the web programming world. I need all the help I can get on the Javascript side.

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of issues with buggy extension addins. To clarify are you using visual studio 2010 with tfs 2012 plugin?

The recommended process for identifying the buggy extension is to disable the extensions one at a time until the buggy one is isolated.

the source control shell for tfs2012 can be installed as a separate shell if needed.

I suspect the script editor extensions however.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I unfortunately won't have time to do further troubleshooting in the short term but when I have time I will and post back results